bpool/BOOT/ is full?
So I wanted to make some (too many to state them all) updates on the thinkpad I haven´t used in a while, when I got this error code:
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.15.0-118-generic_5.15.0-118.128_amd64.deb: cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-118-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-118-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
I did some research and eventually found out that all 1,8GB of the bpool were already used and only 5,2MB are available.
Since my laptop is refurbished, I neither have the > or < key, nor the vertical line or "pipe". So all the solutions I found are not possible for me to go with.
terminal output for: df -h /boot

This question is similar to: How do I free up more space in /boot?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
